# 5SIM не хочет выбирать оператора случайным образом

Tags: python, api, случайные-числа

Остальные строки кода не важны - самое важное только 5SIM. Он работает, но всегда бот выводит, что нет доступных номеров. Но на самом деле они есть, он просто не может их выбрать.

Код:

```
def get_price(i):
try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.db', check_same_thread = False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    info = i.split('|')
    print(i)
    service_id = info[0]
    country_id = info[1]
    site_api = info[2]
    operator = info[3]
    link = info[4]

    if site_api == 'sim5':
        info_number = requests.get(link).json()
        service_data = info_number.get(country_id).get(service_id)
        
        if operator == 'any':
            operators = list(service_data.keys())
            operator = random.choice(operators)

        price = service_data.get('cost')
        
        return site_api, price
    if site_api == 'vak':
        try:
            info_number = requests.get(link).json()
            price = info_number[country_id][service_id]['cost']
            if info_number[country_id][service_id]['count'] == 0 and info_number[country_id][service_id].get('count') == None:
                return site_api, 0
            else:
                return site_api, price
        except:
            if int(country_id) == 0:
                VAK_SMS_TOKEN = cursor.execute('SELECT vak_sms FROM settings').fetchone()[0]
                info_number = requests.get(f'https://vak-sms.com/api/getCountNumber/?apiKey={VAK_SMS_TOKEN}&service={service_id}&country=ru&operator=any&price').json()
                if info_number.get(service_id) != 0 or info_number.get(service_id) != 'None':
                    return 'vak', info_number['price']
    else:
        info_number = requests.get(link).json()
        price = info_number[country_id][service_id].get('cost')
        if info_number[country_id][service_id].get('count') == 0:
            return site_api, 0
        else:
            return site_api, price
except:
    return site_api, 0
```

Пример ответа от 5sim:

```
{"ukraine":{"telegram":{"virtual21":{"cost":26,"count":0,"rate":0},"virtual23":{"cost":25.2,"count":1000,"rate":1.28},"virtual34":{"cost":110,"count":0,"rate":23.33},"virtual4":{"cost":13.4,"count":500,"rate":0}}}}
```

Comment: на этом форуме приято общаться нормально, а не в стиле наблатыканной школоты. так что, впредь, тщательней подбирай выражения.